# Can't call setState function in onSubmit of Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I'm trying to add an alert every time I submit my form. I tried to pass my state as a prop to my component but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my class state:

```
this.state = {
          alert_variant: '',
          alert_heading: '',
          alert_body: '',
          alert_show: false
};
```

Here is how I render my Alert:

```
<ReactAlert 
  show={this.state.alert_show}
  variant={this.state.alert_variant} 
  heading={this.state.alert_heading} 
  body={this.state.alert_body} 
/>
```

Here is a portion of my submit handler in Formik which sends the values to API:

```
onSubmit={(
          values, 
          {
           setSubmitting, 
           resetForm
          }) =>{
                fetch("url.com", {
                        method: 'POST',
                        mode: 'cors',
                        body: JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)
                    }
                )
.then(res => res.json())
.then(
(result) => {
       console.log(result)
       setSubmitting(false)
       resetForm(values)
       this.setState({
               alert_show: true,
               alert_variant: 'success',
               alert_heading: 'Sample Header',
               alert_body: 'Sample body.'
       });
},
    (error, result) => {
                        this.setState({
                            error
                        });
                        console.log(this.state.error);
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    }
                )
```

And here is my Alert component:

```
function ReactAlert(props){
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    if (show) {
        return(
            <Bs.Alert variant={props.variant} onClose={() => setShow(false)} dismissible>
                <Bs.Alert.Heading>{props.heading}</Bs.Alert.Heading>
                <p>
                    {props.body}
                </p>
            </Bs.Alert>
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now how can I change my state variable within the submit handler of Formik? Is that even possible? I tried to create a separate submit handler function but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you create an example of your code on codeSandBox?

Comment: yes it's possible. I think ( this.setState) this keyword should be undefined. please debug and see. below answer should resolve that undefined issue

Comment: @Oshini but the `this` is not producing an undefined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I'm sharing this if there are any beginners out there who will encounter the same problem.

I created a variable to store the `this` instance of the class just like what @Harish Sonis' said in his answer. And I added a function that I call every time the alert is closed.

My function:

```
alertClose(){
     this.setState({
        alert_show: false
     });
}
```

New Alert render, I added the onClose prop:

```
<ReactAlert 
            display={this.state.alert_show}
            variant={this.state.alert_variant} 
            heading={this.state.alert_heading} 
            body={this.state.alert_body} 
            onClose={this.alertClose}
        />
```

I called the onClose prop in the component render

```
function ReactAlert(props){

    if (props.display) {
        return(
            <Bs.Alert variant="success" onClose={() => props.onClose()} dismissible>
                <Bs.Alert.Heading>hehe</Bs.Alert.Heading>
                <p>
                    hehe    
                </p>
            </Bs.Alert>
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks to @Harish Soni for helping me.

Comment: You can mark it as an answer so that it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the `instance of the Current Class inside the fecth` as it creates a new object which scopes until the end.

So if you want to call `setState` inside of another class here is way:

```
onSubmit={(
        values,
        {
          setSubmitting,
          resetForm
        }) => {

        // GET THE CURRENT CLASS INSTANCE:
        const that = this;

        fetch("url.com", {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors',
          body: JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)
        }
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
              console.log(result)
              setSubmitting(false)
              resetForm(values)

              //CALL SETSTATE ON THAT
              that.setState({
                alert_show: true,
                alert_variant: 'success',
                alert_heading: 'Sample Header',
                alert_body: 'Sample body.'
              });
            },
            (error, result) => {

              //CALL SETSTATE ON THAT
              that.setState({
                error
              });
              console.log(that.state.error);
              setSubmitting(false);
            }
          )
      }
```

UPDATE:
For the Alert ONE

```
function ReactAlert(props){
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    if (props.show || props.alert_show) {
        return(
            <Bs.Alert variant={props.variant} onClose={() => setShow(false)} dismissible>
                <Bs.Alert.Heading>{props.heading}</Bs.Alert.Heading>
                <p>
                    {props.body}
                </p>
            </Bs.Alert>
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: But even if when I passed the state variable value to my Alert component it still is not working. `const [show, setShow] = useState(false);` I tried to replace `false` with props.show but still not working.

Comment: I tried to log in the console the value of `props.show` and it shows `true` which is correct but the alert is still not displaying. But when I tried `show={true}` the alert is displayed. I don't know why